# Office 2013 - Save Window issue

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, save-as

I am unable to see the list of files in my SaveAs window. I am also not able to adjust it. is there some setting that I can change?

My SaveAs window looks like this:
[image: SaveAs Office 2013]

Edit:
When I click HideFolders, this is how the window looks like. There are no third party addons installed. Safe mode results in the same behavior.

[image: HideFolders Clicked]

This is happening on all office 2013 products. The rest of the applications are fine.

Comment: What happens when you toggle the Hide Folders button on the bottom left?

Comment: Weird it's like it's hiding the folders, yet showing you the rest. As @nonterrorist asks, what happens if you hit the "Hide folders" link a couple times?  Aside form that: If you log in as anoterh user, does it behave the same way?  If you start the office program in safe mode (ie: `winword.exe /safe`) does it behave the same way?  Have you tried a standard Office repair yet?  Do you have any 3rd party Office add-ons installed?

Comment: If you hit the link again it goes back to the large view, but still no folders shown?  Try as a different user. Try an office repair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The window has been drug up. You need to move your cursor up to the edge of the address bar and when it turns to the resizing arrow, click and drag down.

[image]